# Is it safe to modify database table column datatype directly?

Tags: magento2, database, module, magento-1

I am able to change **Catalog Price Rules**' `from_date` and `to_date` from "date" datatype into "datetime", by overriding the classes:

- Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Main
- Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_CatalogController
- Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule

and changing the datatype of the table columns `catalogrule.from_date` and `catalogrule.to_date` into "datetime".

Is doing the latter safe? Or should I somehow create or modify some files, maybe in an `sql` folder somewhere, e.g. my module's? Or could anyone point me to some resources I can peruse to achieve such? I just want to do this properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it manually but then you have to change it on your every Magento instance. (staging, live).
The safest way to do it is to create a module (use the same module that holds the class rewrites) and include in your module an upgrade script that changes the column.
Something like this:

```
$this->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule')}` CHANGE `from_date` `from_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
");
$this->run("
ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule')}` CHANGE `to_date` `to_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
");
```

This way you can make your changes portable.